# IBM HPC 4.2 different behavior between IBM MPI and OpenMPI under LSF

Tags: lsf

We have an IBM HPC 4.2 with 32 compute nodes.
We did compile and install Openmpi 1.10.1 with lsf support.

The problem :
We have a different behavior between IBM MPI (MPI chipped with the platform or PMPI) and Openmpi when we use them under lsf.

Example :
I did compile hello_world.c mpi example with both implementations, when I launch the execution without lsb (without bsub) I get

**PMPI** : `mpirun -np 4 -hostlist "compute000 compute001" ./hello_world_pmpi.exe`

Hello world! I'm 1 of 4 on compute000

Hello world! I'm 2 of 4 on compute001

Hello world! I'm 3 of 4 on compute001

Hello world! I'm 0 of 4 on compute000

**Openmpi** : `mpirun -np 4 --host "compute000,compute001" --mca btl self,sm --mca mtl psm ./hello_world_ompi.exe`

Hello world! I'm 1 of 4 on compute000

Hello world! I'm 2 of 4 on compute000

Hello world! I'm 3 of 4 on compute001

Hello world! I'm 0 of 4 on compute001

Which is logic, but when I use lsf, things change with PMPI which is more weird !!!! and I get

**PMPI** : `bsub -n 4 -R "span[ptile=2]" -o pmpi-%J.out mpirun ./hello_world_pmpi.exe`

cat pmpi-xxx.out
...

**Hello world! I'm 0 of 1 on compute017**

**Opemmpi** : `bsub -n 4 -R "span[ptile=2]" -o ompi-%J.out mpirun --mca btl self,sm --mca mtl psm ./hello_world_ompi.exe`

cat pmpi-xxx.out
...

**Hello world! I'm 1 of 4 on compute005

Hello world! I'm 2 of 4 on compute010

Hello world! I'm 3 of 4 on compute010

Hello world! I'm 0 of 4 on compute005**

It seems like just one instance of PMPI is launched and not 4.

I have the same problem with IMB (intel benchmark) and HPCC, they complain about lack of processes, without lsf they both work fine, with lsf, only openmpi works correctly.

any Idea?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you need to use the `-lsf` option of the `mpirun` command? https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSF4ZA_9.1.4/pmpi_guide/lsf_integration.dita

Comment: Thanks, and yes, I just read it, the problem is that it is not mentioned on the man page of mpirun command. The correct command will be 
PMPI : bsub -n 4 -R "span[ptile=2]" -o pmpi-%J.out mpirun -lsf ./hello_world_pmpi.exe